# when to use these two sentences

Tags: subjunctives

> I would prefer that she **do** that

and

> I would prefer that she **did** that

Why one is present subjunctive do and the other  past simple did

Answer (score 1):

I prefer she do that. [now]

Certain verbs take a bare infinitive (a better term than subjunctive).
I recommend or advise she go now. Prefer, recommend and advise all take a bare infinitive in the third person.

I would prefer that she did that. [there is less chance of her doing it].

This is structured like: I would prefer if she did that.

I **would like** it if **you did** that. [an second or unreal [some say irrealis] conditional]. That is: If + simple past and the main clause using the present conditional.

Comment: but I would prefer that she do that is correct or not

Comment: it was recommended that the factory close his door at 7 or closed in this case

Comment: that is what I think but I found this example and was surprised

Comment: It was recommended that the company closed its foreign offices. 
  /www.talkenglish.com/grammar/mood.aspx

Comment: Correct sentences for 1, 2, and 4:
1) I wish I would be able to buy this car
2) It was recommended that the company closed its foreign offices.
4) Our manager insists that the group be reorganized.

Answer (score 0):

Both are and can be used in everyday conversations but the correct one is:

> I would prefer that she did that.

Cheers
Travis

Comment: Does this mean that the other one is incorrect?

Comment: I believe strictly grammatically yes.